# Python cx_oracle GetOverlappedResultEx could not be located in kernel32.dll

Tags: python, cx-oracle

I am trying to use cx_Oracle to connect to a database and am getting this error at the point in the code when I issue the cx_Oracle.connect statement.  I am running windows 7 and have tried with both 32 and 64 bit versions of python and the corresponding Oracle Instant Client versions.

If I run through Visual Studio Code I dont get this error but I get the error "DPI-1050: Oracle Client library is at version 0.0 but version 11.2 or higher is needed".  I spent quite some time checking for possible solutions and following the suggestions posted ([this one for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55595250/dpi-1050-oracle-client-library-is-at-version-0-0-but-version-11-2-or-higher-is)) but with no luck.

Comment: Sounds like you need to install the client part first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `GetOverlappedResultEx` WinAPI function is new in Windows 8.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/hh448542)

As such, this means that your copy of `cx_Oracle` (or some DLL that it links against -- perhaps the Oracle client library) does not support your version of Windows.

(btw kudos to package authors for such a helpful error message)

Comment: I was using the latest Instant Client version(19_3) and tried both 32 and 64 bit versions but no joy.  So based on your suggestion I went to the earliest version that is referenced in the error message (11.2) and tried again and problem solved. Many thanks.  I agree .. the error messaging is woeful.

Comment: Did you install the version of the VS Redistributable needed for 19.3?  See https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/issues/351#issuecomment-538785431